# New Google tags and campaign management across multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-data-hub

I have been managing a Google Ads account for 7 years with 2 campaigns each dedicated to a different domain. So 2 campaigns 2 sites in the same account. I have 2 google tag manager accounts with conversions set up for each domain. Now I saw the Google tag appear automatically set to only 1 tag of the 2 sites. Now my doubt is, do I have to create a different account to manage the 2 sites? Or can I combine the 2 old tags together to ensure I can continue to monitor both sites on the same profile? Or would I have a conversion conflict this way? Or a failure to notice something?

I need to know if I should combine all tag, if I can leave everything as is or if I should create a new account to manage the 2 domains separately.